@nestjs/testing and `describe` methods not found
I am using Jest to test my songs.controller.spec.ts file, but VSCode cannot detect the module @nestjs/testing and the describe method on the songs.controller.spec.ts file. The file content is the following (just a default spec file generated by Nest).
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { SongsController } from './songs.controller';

describe('SongsController', () => {
  let controller: SongsController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [SongsController],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<SongsController>(SongsController);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});


Weirdly, describe works on mock-function.spec.js file. It seems to work on JS file but not on TS file. Why?
I have no jest config by default at all. You can check my code structure and its configs here: https://github.com/richard-here/songs-be
